# Feature selection for each class in image classification

Tags: image, classification, feature-selection

I have to do an image classifier (based on already extracted features) on a big db of images, at the same time i have to retrieve the most relevant features for each class. I found a lot of papers on the internet talking about "feature selection" but that is an extraction of the most relevant features for the whole set of images, and that's not what i am interested in. So, how can i do it?

Comment: Please provide some more description for better answers.

Comment: I want to use a SVM classifier on the images (whom i've already had features extracted with LIRe and textual information) in order to get a definition of 5/6 classes. Then, for each class i need to select the most significant features that influence mostly in that specific class.